# Package not found, Gradle build

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

I have the following problem. In my ORMConfiguration file I am setting up some of the basic properties that I need to implement JPA. Inside this ORMConfig.java file, I also have a main class.
The class imports look like this

```
package io.good.asset.ams.dao.configuration;
import io.good.asset.ams.model.domain.Category;
import io.good.asset.ams.model.domain.Company;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import java.util.Map;
```

The project is built using gradle and depencies are set in the following manner:

```
project(':AMSRepository'){
    dependencies {
        compile project(':AMSModel')
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final")
        compile("com.h2database:h2:${h2Ver}")

        testCompile("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:${liquibaseSpringVer}")
    }
}
```

Since this is a multi-modular project the first two imports in my class are pointing to the different module, and when I try to build that complete project from root, or individual AMSRepository module i get error that

> error: package io.good.asset.ams.model.domain does not exist
>   import io.good.asset.ams.model.domain.Category;
>                                        ^
>   error: package io.good.asset.ams.model.domain does not exist
>   import io.good.asset.ams.model.domain.Company;

My settings.gradle looks like this

```
rootProject.name = 'AMS'
include 'AMSRepository'
include 'AMSService'
include 'AMSWeb'
include 'AMSModel'
```

I have also used IntelliJ module settings panel and tried to add manually decencies to this module troublesome module, and the most weird this is that nothing is underlined as wrong and that when I run the main class in ORMConfig.java and instantiate objects from these modules, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you show the "settings.gradle" file in the root project directory?

Comment: @AndroidGuy I edited the question with setting.gradle addition

Answer (score -3):

> Like a war file, a Spring Boot application is not intended to be used
>   as a dependency. If your application contains classes that you want to
>   share with other projects, the recommended approach is to move that
>   code into a separate module. The separate module can then be depended
>   upon by your application and other projects.

[Spring Boot Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar)

Comment: Please add some more detail.